# Aggregating multiple queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to combine multiple queries into an overall summary query. My current attempt gives an error because my subquery `(SELECT (oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice) AS LineTotal FROM oitems INNER JOIN orders ON oitems.orderid = orders.orderid) AS OrderTotal` returns more than 1 result.

My base queries:

```
SELECT orders.invoicenum AS InvoiceId, customers.contactid AS CustomerId, FORMAT(orders.odate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS OrderDate, 
   orders.oshipfirstname AS FirstName, orders.oshiplastname AS LastName, orders.oshipcompany AS Company, 
   orders.oshipaddress AS Address1, orders.oshipaddress2 AS Address2, orders.oshipcity AS City, orders.oshipcountry AS Country, 
   orders.oshipstate AS State, orders.oshipzip AS Zip, 'Direct' AS Channel, orders.oemail AS Email
FROM orders LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.ocustomerid = customers.contactid
WHERE (orders.invoicenum > 0);
```

.

```
SELECT oitems.orderitemid AS OrderItemId, orders.invoicenum AS InvoiceId, oitems.itemid AS Sku, oitems.numitems AS Qty, oitems.unitprice AS Price 
FROM orders INNER JOIN oitems ON orders.orderid = oitems.orderid;
```

.

```
SELECT (oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice) AS LineTotal FROM oitems;
```

And now my combination attempt:

```
SELECT CustomerId, InvoiceId, OrderDate, FirstName, LastName, Company, Address1, Address2, City, Country, State, Zip, Channel, Email, OrderTotal, ShipFee, Tax 
FROM (SELECT orders.invoicenum AS InvoiceId, customers.contactid AS CustomerId, FORMAT(orders.odate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS OrderDate, 
         orders.oshipfirstname AS FirstName, orders.oshiplastname AS LastName, orders.oshipcompany AS Company, 
         orders.oshipaddress AS Address1, orders.oshipaddress2 AS Address2, orders.oshipcity AS City, orders.oshipcountry AS Country, 
         orders.oshipstate AS State, orders.oshipzip AS Zip, 'Direct' AS Channel, orders.oemail AS Email, orders.oshipcost AS ShipFee, orders.otax AS Tax, 
         (SELECT (oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice) AS LineTotal FROM oitems INNER JOIN orders ON oitems.orderid = orders.orderid) AS OrderTotal 
      FROM orders LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.ocustomerid = customers.contactid
      WHERE (orders.invoicenum > 0)) BaseData;
```

How can I structure this query to return the expected data?

Expected data:

```
CustomerId, InvoiceId, OrderDate, FirstName, LastName, Company, Address1, Address2, City, Country, State, Zip, Channel, Email, OrderTotal, ShipFee, Tax
```

Comment: Do you want to return one row per order, or one row per order item?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov One row per order. This is going to be a "summary" query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reorganized query should be closer to what you want. Sometimes, a JOIN to a derived table is simpler.

```
SELECT CustomerId, 
    InvoiceId, 
    OrderDate, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Company, 
    Address1, 
    Address2, 
    City, 
    Country, 
    State, 
    Zip, 
    Channel, 
    Email, 
    OrderTotal, 
    ShipFee, 
    Tax 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        orders.invoicenum AS InvoiceId, 
        customers.contactid AS CustomerId, 
        FORMAT(orders.odate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS OrderDate, 
        orders.oshipfirstname AS FirstName, 
        orders.oshiplastname AS LastName, 
        orders.oshipcompany AS Company, 
        orders.oshipaddress AS Address1, 
        orders.oshipaddress2 AS Address2, 
        orders.oshipcity AS City, 
        orders.oshipcountry AS Country, 
        orders.oshipstate AS State, 
        orders.oshipzip AS Zip, 
        'Direct' AS Channel, 
        orders.oemail AS Email, 
        orders.oshipcost AS ShipFee, 
        orders.otax AS Tax, 
        OrderTotal.OrdTotal
    FROM orders 
    LEFT JOIN customers 
        ON orders.ocustomerid = customers.contactid
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            oitems.orderid,
            Sum(oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice) OrdTotal 
        FROM oitems
        GROUP BY oitems.Orderid
        ) AS OrderTotal 
        ON OrderTotal.OrderID = orders.orderid
    WHERE orders.invoicenum > 0
    ) BaseData;
```

Comment: Thinking about it the wrong way -- always my problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should write `sum(oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice)` instead of `(oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice)`?

```
SELECT CustomerId, InvoiceId, OrderDate, FirstName, LastName, Company, Address1, Address2, City, Country, State, Zip, Channel, Email, OrderTotal, ShipFee, Tax 
FROM (SELECT orders.invoicenum AS InvoiceId, customers.contactid AS CustomerId, FORMAT(orders.odate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS OrderDate, 
         orders.oshipfirstname AS FirstName, orders.oshiplastname AS LastName, orders.oshipcompany AS Company, 
         orders.oshipaddress AS Address1, orders.oshipaddress2 AS Address2, orders.oshipcity AS City, orders.oshipcountry AS Country, 
         orders.oshipstate AS State, orders.oshipzip AS Zip, 'Direct' AS Channel, orders.oemail AS Email, orders.oshipcost AS ShipFee, orders.otax AS Tax, 
         (SELECT sum(oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice) AS LineTotal FROM oitems  where oitems.orderid = orders.orderid) AS OrderTotal 
      FROM orders LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.ocustomerid = customers.contactid
      WHERE (orders.invoicenum > 0)) BaseData;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that sums the totals in the entire database, not a total for each order. Each order can have a different order total, and I need to multiply the item quantity by the per-item price to reach this order total - hence the subquery. It returns a row for every order, however, which causes the "subquery returns more than 1 result" error.

Comment: Essentially I need something like `SELECT (oitems.numitems * oitems.unitprice) AS LineTotal FROM oitems INNER JOIN orders ON oitems.orderid = orders.orderid) AS OrderTotal WHERE orders.orderid = '123456';`, but I cannot specify each orderid manually.

Comment: Hm - you may correlate the query to the other values in the outer select clause; can you restrict `orders.orderid` to a specific value?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. This query is supposed to produce a "clean" summary of all order data in the database - so I cannot limit it to a specific orderid. I need the subquery to return only the 1 result from whatever the current result set's row orderid is. Something like `orderid = orderid`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Tried to correlate the subquery; can you check if it works?

Comment: It works! I see you ditched the `INNER JOIN` in favor of a typical `WHERE` clause. I think that's where I was getting off track. Thank you!